# tensorflow branch graph based on number of runs

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run a program where essentially I want to be able to branch in a computation graph. I'm not sure if I should be using some sort of scoping for the variables or `tf.cond`. Below is a snippet. Basically, whenever the class is initialized, `update` is ran so I want variable `A` to be set to a random `3 x m` tensor. After `update` runs once, the class attribute `B` should now exist. All subsequent times that `update` runs, I want `A` to be set to `tf.matmul(tf.transpose(self.B), tf.random_normal((3, self.m), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float64))`. Any ideas on how to make that happen?

```
class MatrixOps():

    def __init__(self, m, n, init_data):
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

        self.X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[self.m, None])
        self._build_graph()

        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        self.sess.run(init)
        self.update(init_data)

    def _build_graph(self):
        A = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((3, self.m), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float64))
        self.B = tf.matmul(A, self.X)
        A.assign(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(self.B), tf.random_normal((3, self.m), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float64)))

    def update(self, X):
        return self.sess.run(self.B, feed_dict={self.X: X})
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your problem here, but let's analyse what your code is doing :

You do _build_graph that create a Variable A, that should be randomly initialized, then a Tensor B that is the multiplication between A and X.
Then you create a assign op, that says that A should be equal to B^t @ M with M a random matrix. (@ is the matrix multiplication)

You run your initialization, that's when A become a real random tensor.

Finally you run update that compute B (but it not used)

Your update in the `__init__` is therefore useless, and your assign operation is added to the graph, but you have no reference on it. Therefore this operation will never happen. What you should do is keep a reference to this like

```
self.A_assign = A.assign(tf.matmul(tf.transpose(self.B), tf.random_normal((3, self.m), 0, 1, dtype=tf.float64)))
```

And then in your update, you run both ops, in the order you want.
If you want to compute B then assign A it's like this:

```
def update(self, X):
    # Compute B
    B_res = self.sess.run(self.B, feed_dict={self.X: X})
    # Assign A
    self.sess.run(self.A_assign)
    # Return the result
    return B_res
```

If you want to do it in the other order:

```
def update(self, X):
    # Assign A
    self.sess.run(self.A_assign)
    # Return the result of B
    return self.sess.run(self.B, feed_dict={self.X: X})
```

Finally, but it should not be useful in your case, but just FYI, to do conditional things, you should use `tf.where` (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where)

Comment: Thanks! Any recommendations for the case where the `M` in `A.assign(M)` is not the shape shape as `A`? For example `InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [121,2000] rhs shape= [121,2010]`

Comment: Why do you want to assign matrices with different shapes? If you don't know your shape at runtime or it can change, you should use a placeholder and affect it with the value you want with feed_dict.
`A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[121, None])` and with your matrix M: `session.run(op, feed_dict:{A:M})`, where op is the operation you want to achieve. Here `None` says that you don't know this size yet.